# swagger parameterized type in response

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I use Swagger with SprigBoot.
And i have  as an response in controllers

```
 class CostumResponse<T> {
       boolean success;
       T data;
}


@GetMapping
public CostumResponse<Data> getDataById(){
    return CostumResponse.ok(data);
}
```

And I need to get to swagger api kind of

```
{ success: true,
  data: {
      someFiled1: xxx,
      someField2: yyy
  }
}
```

How can I do this, because I can’t write on controllerMethod

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 201, response = SuccessResponse<Data>.class),
})
```

I use swagger 2.0